# node glob pattern for files not in folders starting with underscore

Tags: node.js, glob

I've a directory structure as follows:

```
source
├── _assets
│   ├── css
│   └── js
├── _config.yaml
├── downloads
│   ├── hello2.txt
│   └── hello.txt
├── hello_world
│── robots.txt
└── favicon.ico
```

I'm using the node package [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to list files that follow a certain pattern. I want to list all files that are not in a folder whose name starts with an underscore ![_*]. The patterns I've tried include various combinations of

```
const pattern1 = `${sourceDirPath}/!(_*)**`
const pattern2 = `${sourceDirPath}/!(_*)/**`
```

`pattern1` only gives me files like `[source/robots.txt, source/favicon.ico]` whereas `pattern2` only gives me files like `[source/downloads/hello.txt, source/downloads/hello2.txt]`

Can anyone give me some hint which pattern will let me have files from both patterns? Or do I have to look for both patterns and then merge the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using ignore

```js
const pattern = `${sourceDirPath}/**`;
const ignorePattern = `${sourceDirPath}/_*/**`;
glob(pattern, {
  ignore: [ignorePattern],
  nodir: true,
}, callback);
```